# Getting Error in output of web-mail while pasting html signature (Difference of output expected vs original )

Tags: html, css, html-table, cpanel, webmail

I want to make an html signature for my webmail. I have following html signature.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>last-one</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <table id="Table_01" width="900" height="420" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_01.png" width="960" height="119" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <a href="tel:+919810159700"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_02.png" width="960" height="109" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <a href="tel:+919810154339"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_03.png" width="960" height="16" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <a href="tel:+911244064157"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_04.png" width="960" height="19" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <a href="mailto:hanishgupta@jdindia.net"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_05.png" width="960" height="30" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <a href="mailto:info@sunkind.in"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_06.png" width="960" height="26" alt=""></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_07.png" width="960" height="88" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="https://facebook.com"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_08.png" width="179" height="79" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://twitter.com"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_09.png" width="34" height="79" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://linkedin.com"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_10.png" width="35" height="79" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="https://youtube.com"><img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_11.png" width="40" height="79" alt=""></a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="EMAIL-SIGNETURE-2_12.png" width="675" height="79" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

And my expected output if following

[image]

But when i paste the html code in Web mail html signature section my output slightly change which look like this.

[image]

Can you please tell me what's wrong with expected vs original output?

Answer (score 0):

try this if css:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

or inline html style

```
<table id="Table_01" width="900" height="420" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Comment: can you add the images in table, it seems the image paths were broken in html

Comment: How to add them in table any clue .?

Comment: just the way you uploaded [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL832.png) and call the respective path. hope it works